# Unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor.

It is to be noted that virtualization is enabled.

[image: Virtualization is enabled.]

`Emulator Process for AVD was killed` shown while running the code in `Visual Studio` while trying to install the Hypervisor Driver in Android Studio.

[image: Couldn't install the Hypervisor Driver in Android Studio. "Emulator Process for AVD was killed" shown while running the code in Visual Studio.]

Error is also shown in `Android Studio` while installing the Hypervisor Driver:

[image: Error shown in Android Studio while installing the Hypervisor Driver]

What to do now? Thanks.

Comment: wait!!! your cpu is intel not amd. use haxm. why are you trying to install amd drivers. they are only for amd cpus.

Comment: the first pic shows your cpu is intel 7200u. use haxm.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drdncwC2NgQ    this saved me

Answer (score 10):

If you are using AVAST antivirus, It will not work .. So open Avast antivirus UI and go to Menu / Setting / troubleshooting  and clear the tick on (( Enable hardware-assisted virtualization )) and restart. It will be installed.

Comment: I had already made sure that virtualisation was enabled in the BIOS and tried manually running the silent_install.bat after using the release packages online. Neither worked but this sorted the problem. Only thing to add is that your computer will need restarting once you change the setting in Avast.

Answer (score 3):

First you should try to see if you have Hyper-V enabled. In most cases, the newer computers use it for hardware acceleration but it doesn't share with other virtualization apps, so to run this on an AMD or Intel VT-x first check if you have Hyper-V installed (go to your control panel, then in Programs and Features window, click “Turn Windows features on or off.” then look for Hyper-V and clear the checkbox then click OK.

If that doesn't work check your BIOS permissions, you can go to advanced CPU configuration or chipset and

- find the "Intel Virtualization Technology", enable this option,

or

- on AMD enable the SVM

then Save and Exit.

Answer (score 2):

> If you are using AVAST antivirus, It will not work .. So open Avast antivirus UI and go to Menu / Setting / troubleshooting and clear the tick on (( Enable hardware-assisted virtualization )) and restart. It will be installed.

This method by Tamer works for me but you have to restart your computer for it to be effective.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge when trying to add Bluestacks as an emulator in Android Studio and this was my solution.
Open PowerShell as Admin and do this command:

> Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V

A restart should follow and all should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you tried installing an AMD Virtualization driver for your Intel-CPU. As other people already suggested, try to install the Intel-Driver instead.

The installation probably failed because the program detected your not using an amd-cpu, so there's no point in installing it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Enable Virtualization in your windows/ Mac/ others, and then install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processor.

you may also refer this link to Enable virtualization on Windows [enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-virtualization-on-windows-11-pcs-c5578302-6e43-4b4b-a449-8ced115f58e1)