# Android Hypervisor for AMD installation failed

Tags: android-studio, amd-processor, hypervisor

I did everything from enabling SVM in BIOS, disabling Hyper-V, virtual machine platform, and hypervisor platform, I also tried enabling them still same error, virtualization on Task manager is also enabled, I don't use any antivirus and disabled windows defender, any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Sorry, but here's the error 

"Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors"

Comment: Quick question: You sure your CPU is AMD instead of Intel? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218262/unable-to-install-android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processor)

Comment: Yes, i have Ryzen 5 3600 on B450 chipset