# Can't install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD processors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to install the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors with NO SUCCESS

I installed Android Studio and went to tools/SDK manager -> SDK tools (as specified in Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors - Canary SDK Package, Install Instructions, https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html)

But the process fails. I attached print screens for you to see what I'm doing

### I also get the following error:

Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@8ea29c5c"
(extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver)
should be installed in
"C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver"
but
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2"
instead.
java.net.UnknownHostException: dl.google.com

### Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD
Processors (installer): dl.google.com.

And I also noticed that when doing it, at the bottom of the screen, at the left, it says "daemon started successfully", and at the right, it says "unzipping...", and this process never ends

### The log for the whole process is:

Preparing "Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.7.0)".
Warning: Package "com.android.repository.impl.generated.v2.RemotePackage@8ea29c5c" (extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver) should be installed in
"C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver" but
it already exists.
Installing in "C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2" instead.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gvm-windows_v1_7_0.zip
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.7.0)" ready.
Installing Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) in C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.7.0)" complete.
"Install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors (installer) (revision: 1.7.0)" finished.
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\31.0.0\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\32.0.0-rc1\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2\package.xml
Warning: Observed package id 'extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2' (Expected 'C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver')
Warning: Already observed package id 'extras;google;Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver' in 'C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver-2'
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-31\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86\package.xml
Parsing C:\Users\rafae\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Android SDK is up to date.
Running Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installer
[SC] ControlService FAILED 1062:

The service has not been started.

### [SC] DeleteService SUCCESS
[SC] StartService FAILED with error 4294967201.
Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors installation failed. To install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors
Done

It says that the emulator driver already exists, but I'm not doing anything for it to happen

I followed this instruction but I still can't install it

Could you please tell me what Can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: Some questions to look at:
[Can't install Android Emulator for AMD Processors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59549988),
[How to use Android Emulator on AMD Ryzen (Android Studio)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61047505),
[Android Studio Emulator is not working on Windows 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68373280),
[Unable to install Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63218262).